# How to get height=100% on <object> Embed

Tags: html, css, object, height, embed

I'm trying to insert the following code but it is not working.
I am not able to get 100% height with this. Can anyone help me?
Thanks!

```
<body style="overflow:hidden;">
<TABLE align=left width=234 border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<TR>
    <TD valign=top align=center WIDTH="234" >
        <object data="EmbedPage.html" type="text/html"  style="width: 230px;height:100%;"></object>
    </TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</body>
```

Comment: Short answer is that the container should also be 100%.

Comment: I found this and worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16326445/embedding-pdf-file-within-html-with-100-width-and-height

Answer (score 31):

Use **100vh** for **height**, if you want to span the embed-object over the **full-screen**.

```
<body>
   <object data="EmbedPage.html" type="text/html"  style="width:100%;height:100vh;">
   </object>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't think @user2261793 will ever accept a right answer, but this one worked for me.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I get two scroll bars, one for the object content and one for the page.

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
<body style="overflow:hidden;height:100%;">
    <object data="EmbedPage.html" type="text/html"  style="float:left;width:230px;height:100%;">
    </object>
</body>
```

Comment: It doesn't work... I not get 100% height
Take a look at screen shot here: http://clip2net.com/s/54unnx

Comment: can you just put it on jsfiddle.net

Comment: I also need to disable scroll

Comment: which scroll on the body or on the object

Answer (score 2):

Just remove it from the table.

```
<BODY style="overflow:hidden; height:100%;">

<object data="http://www.misgeret.co.il/Ebay/Famus/SideMenuFamus.html" type="text/html"  style="float:left;width:230px;height:100%"></object>

</BODY>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ma9ic/QtKMa/5/

100% height in a table cell is always a pain. Technically speaking a TD has no height (because that depends on its contents). What you are asking the browser to do is make the child 100% of its parent, which is 100% of its child, which is 100% of its parent ... You can see how that might be a problem.

You could try adding an explicit height to the TD and using table-layout:fixed on the table. At least that way the browser knows the height of the parent without needing the height of the child but that still may not work.

You might need to rethink how you go about this.

This shows you the result using a set height and using iframes

```
<BODY style="overflow:hidden;height:100%;">

<TABLE align=left width=234 border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<TR>
    <TD valign=top align=center WIDTH="234" height="1000">
    <iframe src="http://www.misgeret.co.il/Ebay/Famus/SideMenuFamus.html" style="border:0px #FFFFFF none;" name="myiFrame" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
    </TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>

</BODY>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ma9ic/QtKMa/6/

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still see the scroll,
I need no scroll + using the table element because the page consist more elements base on tables, change all the page is very complicate...

There is no other way I can do it?

Comment: Thank you,
I start thinking it is more complicated than rewrite the code with divs...

Anyway, I can't use iframe, I need to use only OBJECT element, How can I disable the scroll on the "div" version? (and still get 100% height "automatically")

http://jsfiddle.net/QtKMa/3/

Comment: overflow-y:hidden;
overflow-x:hidden;

Answer (score 1):

```
body, html{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

<body>
    <table class="flash-container" style="height: 100%; width:100%">
        <tr style="height: 100%; width:100%">
            <td style="height: 100%; width:100%">
                <object width="100%" height="100%">
                    <param name="autoPlay" value="true"></param>
                    <embed allowfullscreen="true" autoPlay="true" flashvars="autoplay=true&play=ture" allownetworking="all" id="pptShow" allowscriptaccess="always" height="100%" src="http://www.weilaijiaoxue.com:9096/upload/2016/4/13/swf_20160413115509559.swf"  type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%"></embed>
                </object>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code and it rendered perfectly in width and height of the browser
style="width:100vw;height:100vh;"